# Shell Script command not found error

Tags: bash, shell

Below my script for up to `n` prime numbers. When I run it, it always shows an error that command not found in line 12 and 18 both. What am I doing wrong?

```
clear    
echo"enter the number upto which you want prime numbers : "    
read n

for((i=1;i<=n;i++))    
do    
    flag=0 
    for((j=2;j<i;j++))
    do
        if [expr $i % $j-eq 0]    
        then
            flag=1
        fi
    done

    if [$flag-eq 0]
    then
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

Comment: Put space around `[` and `]` in `if` condition.

Comment: use http://www.shellcheck.net/ for such issues, you can install it locally as well...

Comment: also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 use `(( ))` for arithmetic comparisons

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in comments, you must use spaces around `[` and `]`, as well as the comparison operators. Even more safe when using `[` and `]` is quoting your variables to avoid word splitting (not actually required in this specific case, though).

Additionally, you want to compare the *output* of `expr` to 0, so you have to use command substitution:

```
if [ $(expr "$i" % "$j") -eq 0 ]
```

and

```
if [ "$flag" -eq 0 ]
```

Since you're using Bash, you can use the `(( ))` compound command:

```
if (( i % j == 0 ))
```

and

```
if (( flag == 0 ))
```

No `expr` needed, no command substitution, no quoting required, no `$` required, and the comparison operators have their "normal", expected meaning.

Comment: `if [ expr "$i" % "$j" -eq 0 ]` - gives to many argument error. I think its better to execute it as command `\`expr $ ...\``

Comment: The point is that `(( ))` is so much simpler that you never actually have to use the external command `expr`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of syntax errors other than the brackets of if statement. Kindly go through the piece of code below. I have checked it running on my system.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "enter the number upto which you want prime numbers : "
read n

for((i=1;i<=n;i++))
do
  flag=0
  for((j=2;j<i;j++))
  do
    if [ `expr $i % $j` -eq 0 ]
      then flag=1
    fi
  done

  if [ $flag -eq 0 ]
    then echo $i
  fi
done
```